# undefined method 'book_id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopping-cart

I'm trying to make a simple book ordering application in Ruby on Rails and have been running into some problems. I am trying to create a "place an order" page from a link from each product, so that on this second page the book information is there and then there's just a form to fill in the quantity the customer wants. However I keep running into the undefined method 'book_id' for nil:NilClass error specified above (and when I delete that line of code I run into the same error on the next one - i.e. undefined method 'order_id').

Here's my code for the view that I keep messing up on:

```
<%= @order_item.book_id %>
<%= @order_item.order_id %>
<%= @order_item.total_pricel %>
<%= form_for @order_item.quantity do |f| %>
<%= f.label :quantity %>:
<%= f.text_field :quantity %><br />
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

My OrderItem model should have the foreign keys order_id and book_id.

Here's my OrderItem model:

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :order
belongs_to :book

validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: {only_integer: true, greater_than: 0}
validate :book_present
validates :price, presence: true
validate :order_present

def unit_price
    if persisted?
        self[:unit_price]
    else
        book.price
    end
end

def total_price
    unit_price * quantity
end

private
    def book_present
        if book.nil?
            errors.add(:book, "is not valid.")
        end
    end


def order_present
    if order.nil?
        errors.add(:order, "is not a valid order.")
        end
    end

def finalize
    self[:unit_price] = unit_price
    self[:total_price] = quantity * self[:unit_price]
end
end
```

And here's the controller:

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    @order.save
    session[:order_id] = @order.id
end

def update
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.update_attributes(order_item_params)
    @order_items = @order.order_items
end

def destroy
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.destroy
    @order_item = @order.order_items
end

private
def order_item_params
    params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :book_id)
end
end
```

In addition to this being my first Rails project, I'm generally very new to coding and would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

Your view isn't getting the `@order_item` instance variable from the controller.  If it's on your 'show' view then in your OrderItem Controller you will need a defined action like this for example:

```
def show
  @order_item = OrderItem.find(params[:id])
end
```

I also see a potential issue with your form..you have `form_for @item_order.quantity`.  Take out the .quantity part so that's it's just `form_for @item_order`.  Your form is bound to the `@item_order` object and it will know to save the quantity attribute from the `f.text_field :quantity` part of the form

Answer (score 0):

Ok...First of all,`you must need a book,order present in the db` before you make or create items.So you need to first check if there is a book created,order created and then use both of them to create item.

So i assume,you `item.rb` model will have something like :-

```
belongs_to :book
belongs_to :order
```

And `book.rb`

```
has_many :items,:dependent=>:destroy
```